# Fedora 21: Command not found

Tags: bash, fedora

I have a bash script in `/home/istvan/myadmin/run-web-server.sh`. It has only one line: `systemctl start lighttpd.service`. I made it executable thru `chmod +x` and it works fine. Then I run `#ln -s /home/istvan/myadmin/run-web-server.sh /usr/local/bin/run-web-server`. Link is created without problems. If I run  `#/usr/local/bin/run-web-server` it is executed. But when I type `#run-web-server` I get `'command not found'`. When I type `echo $PATH` it displays `/usr/local/bin` among other directories

Comment: Type `hash -r` to update the shell's command cache.

Comment: Still I get the same error. Maybe I should reboot?

Comment: That's overkill. Just logout and login again

Comment: I thought hash rebuilding would only help if you moved the location of a previously cached command

Comment: Command not found again

Comment: does `which run-web-server` produce any output? I think you possibly have a PATH problem, maybe a typo?

Comment: It produces `/usr/local/bin/run-web-server`

Comment: When I run it without `sudo`, but simply as `run-web-server` the file is found and asks for password! But with `sudo`, `'command not found'`

Comment: Solved the problem by moving the script from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin`!

Comment: While that might have fixed the immediate issue with `run-web-server` I wouldn't necessarily say it solved the problem because if all was really okay there shouldn't have been a issue in the first place.  Something is wrong somewhere and I'd look into it further.